# Changing culture when switching view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a website web site where each user has a culture setting to allow control of resources displayed. The main page has two views, one the log on screen, the second the main menu.

When first loaded the page displays with the culture settings of the previous user (if any). If I then log on as a user with a different culture setting the view changes to the main menu without changing the culture. Go to another page and the user's correct culture settings are picked up, go back to the main menu, uses the correct culture etc.

This is logical but is there a way (without redesigning the site to have a separate log in page and main menu) to reset the culture to the new user's when switching view?

Answer (score 0):

response.redirect does the job